# git push origin master says Everything up-to-date when I've edited & committed files

Tags: git, github

I edited 2 files and performed git operations.

```
git add script.html script.js script.css
git commit -m "Updated"
git status
# On branch gh-pages
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   index.html
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
```

Why does it show **Everything up-to-date** when I've edited files ? I can't see the changes reflected in github.

Comment: "On branch gh-pages" vs "git push origin master". Did you mean `git push origin gh-pages` or `git push origin gh-pages:master`?

Comment: I meant `git push origin master`. Oh. I can see that this got reflected in ghs-pages !

Comment: you need to `git push -u origin gh-pages` (if you have never pushed that branch before), or `git push origin`

Comment: @anjanesh, did you find the answer eventually? Could you please add it? (Google brought me here, having the same problem.) Thanks!

Comment: If your problem is not solved yet, can you provide us the result of the following command: `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all -10`? If your problem is already solved, update the post with the solution and indicate it as answered in order to help other users with the same kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you performed your commits on `gh-pages`, not on master. If you push `gh-pages`, it will push the changes you committed.